# How to use Alamofire installed for another project

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I installed `Alamofire` for a project using `CocoaPods`.
Now I want to use it in another project. I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Your two projects should have two independent podfiles and you should be able to install even the same pods in two entirely different projects. Just pod install like you did in your first project and you are done.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much!